# Sorting based on permutations of a certain size

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql

I need to sort a user into a group based on permutations of 11 foreign keys (1-11).

I have a big_table:

```
FK |  User_ID            FK  |  User_ID
1  |  a                   4  |  c
5  |  a                   1  |  c
3  |  b                   5  |  c
9  |  b                   11 |  c
7  |  b                   2  |  c
```

- Group 1 (G1) will include any permutation of size 2 (user a in this example)
- G2 will include any permutation of size 3 (user b)
- G3 will include any permutation of size 4 up to size 11 (user c)

The valid permutations will be stored in separate tables, a table for all permutations of size 2, another for permutations of size 3 etc.

How can I check if a user meets the requirements to fit into a group?

(Efficiency is preferable but a working solution is the goal). Sorry I don't have any code but I'm new enough to SQL that I don't know where to start with this problem.

> EDIT: There are other groups and more foreign keys, G1-G3 are only applicable to FK's 1-11.
>
> the issue I'm having the most trouble wrapping my head around is how to compare multiple FK's to a single permutation. For example, how can i compare

```
 1  |  a   and  3  |  a
```

> to a list of valid permutations algorithmically?

Comment: What are the results you are looking for?

Comment: @Ridiculon You really want to try to show at least some attempt at solving this yourself.  See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Comment: this is part of a much larger problem that i'm stuck on that i've stripped down as much as possible. The whole problem involves more (and more complicated) groups, but I know that if i can get an answer to this aspect i'll be able to apply it to the rest of the problem. Part of the issue is that I don't know very much about sql beyond ddl statements, i'm looking for someone who has more experience to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You may not have a query to show, yet. But table definition (showing data types and constraints) and Postgres version should be easy to provide. Please edit your question.

Comment: I don't understand anything about tthis question. What is the role of the FKs ? are you looking for a way to generate *tableaus* ? Or ar the just three groops a={1,5} b={3,7,9} c={ 1,2,4,5,11} and you want to generate all possible 2*3*5 triplets ? Please rephrase ...

Comment: I'm not looking to generate the permutations. You can assume that valid permutations have already been generated and stored in their own table, a different table for each size (actually i may make another question to ask whether that is the best way to do that). I am looking for a way to check if a user meets the criteria to be fit into a group.

 I'll add this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the number of foreign keys, use `count(*)` or `count(distinct)`:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from big_table
group by user_id;
```

This will give the number of foreign keys for each user (assuming no duplicates in the table).

Comment: I should have mentioned that the 1-11 foreign keys are not the only ones in the column. adding it to the original question